# Group second column based on first column awk

Tags: awk

Can someone please help in parsing the following data. Below are the input, output and tried attempt details.

Input data:

```
foo 1
bar 12
foo 23
foo 45
bar 223
bar 123
bar 3478
foo 45
zoo 1
zoo 0987
foo 5
```

Output data:

```
foo 1 23 45 45 5

bar 12 223 123 3478 

zoo 1 0987
```

Attempt(Failed):

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2;next}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' input
zoo 0987
foo 5
bar 3478
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{map[$1] = map[$1] OFS $2} END {for (i in map) print i map[i] ORS}' file

zoo 1 0987

foo 1 23 45 45 5

bar 12 223 123 3478
```

If you want to maintain original order of keys then use:

```sh
awk '!($1 in map) {ord[++n] = $1} {map[$1] = map[$1] OFS $2} END {for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) print ord[i] map[ord[i]] ORS}' file

foo 1 23 45 45 5

bar 12 223 123 3478

zoo 1 0987
```